# Utilizar a tag <a download href=""> passando endereço https para o href

Tags: html5, download

estou tentando efetuar o download de um arquivo, passando um endereço https, segue exemplo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <body>
              <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" download> download</a>
        </body>
   </html>
```

porém ao invés de baixar o arquivo, está abrindo.

Comment: Já tentou com algum tipo de arquivo que não seja imagem? Acredito que neste caso haja alguma configuração do navegador para abrir a imagem ao invés de baixá-la.

Comment: Já, essa tag "download" só funciona no Edge :(

Comment: O atributo download funciona em outros navegadores, acredito que todos, pelo menos os principais, chrome, firefox, opera, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publiquei, na integra, seu código no meu servidor e realmente ao invés de baixar o arquivo, está abrindo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
          <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png" download> download</a>
    </body>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <body>
          <a href="1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.png" download> download</a>
    </body>
```

### CONCLUSÃO

> Por questões lógicas e até de segurança, quem decide o download é o desenvolvedor de site. Eu posso disponibilizar download de qualquer arquivo desde que esteja publicado no meu domínio. Não fosse assim qualquer um poderia baixar qualquer arquivo da rede.

---

**Com Jquery `(para imagens)` é possível abrir a janelinha de download diretamente**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

    var image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png";
    // get file name - you might need to modify this if your image url doesn't contain a file extension otherwise you can set the file name manually
    var fileName = image.src.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var blob;
        // ... get as Data URI
        if (image.src.indexOf(".jpg") > -1) {
        blob = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        } else if (image.src.indexOf(".png") > -1) {
        blob = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        } else if (image.src.indexOf(".gif") > -1) {
        blob = canvas.toDataURL("image/gif");
        } else {
        blob = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
        $("body").html("<br><a download='" + fileName + "' href='" + blob + "'>download</a>");
    };

</script>
```

Bibliografia [canvas](http://HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL())

Comment: Desculpe, mas acho que não compreendi o seu último comentário. Primeiro diz que seria *infantil* abrir a imagem, mas termina dizendo que ao abrir teria a opção do *download* ( o que refere-se que não há porquê forçar o *download* de início).

Comment: Ao invés de down dê uma solução melhor!!

Comment: Não sei se é necessário justificar, mas o voto negativo não é meu. Só questionei porque realmente não havia entendido o que tinha dito.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, blz, não pensei que tivesse sido você. Editei a resposta e acho que vão entender melhor a pergunta e a resposta

Comment: Resolveu o problema, muito obrigado :)

Comment: tentei efetuar o download de um arquivo .pdf, porém não estou conseguindo, segue o link do arquivo teste:http://www.protec.org.br/uploads/agendas/arquivos/DOCUMENTO%20TESTE%20PDF.pdf

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, mas caso eu não salve no meu servidor e faça via Jquery, seria possível?

Comment: @Flavio, demorei mas conclui a resposta, acho que você vai entender!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo  agora entendi, muito obrigado :D